# PHP GD library turns merged image from green to orange

Tags: php, php-gd

I have two gif images, one with a gray gradient background, and one image with a logo. So for example, in the images below, the green box is the logo.

My problem is that when I merge the two gif files using the PHP GD library, the green some how becomes orange/brown and won't return the original colour. Please can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
  $base_image = 'img_in.gif';
  $logo_image = 'logo.gif';

  // Create images from files
  $source   = imagecreatefromgif($base_image);
  $logo   = imagecreatefromgif($logo_image);

  //---------------------Logo-----------------------------------\\
  imagecolortransparent($logo, imagecolorallocate($logo, 0, 0, 0));
  imagecopymerge($source, $logo, 152, 33, 0, 0, 153, 26, 100);

  // -------------------------------Output--------------------------\\
  imagegif($source,$image_out);
  imagedestroy($source);
```

The green one is how it should look
The orange one is how it ends up looking
[image: This is how it should look]

[image: This is how it ends up looking]

The above is how it should look
The above is how it ends up looking

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in the limited colour palette of the gif format, but cannot give you a solution. Though if that's ok, switching the output to png would probably solve you problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Since GIFs are pallet-base**, each [GIF can use 256 colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) only - those allocated in its palette. 
If you copy one GIF into another one, the library needs to somehow homogenize palettes.

I'd propose to **convert those GIFs to PNG** (or some format with more colors), do the processing and finally convert back to GIF.

In general, results should look better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did use it as a png, however, the quality was very poor with a lot of noise in the finished image. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys. I realised that I was saving the gif with only 63 colours and not 256! Doh! Thanks anyway